# Application stops with message like "Unfortunately Soduku has Stopped"

Tags: android, sudoku

I am totally new to Android . I am using the book Hello, Android. I have created a button for "about" that displays information about the sudoku game. But as soon as i click it, the application stops saying "Unfortunately sudoku has stopped".

02-22 09:27:27.693: E/AndroidRuntime(554): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 02-22 09:27:27.693: E/AndroidRuntime(554): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.example.sudoku/org.example.sudoku.About}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class scrollview 02-22 09:27:27.693: E/AndroidRuntime(554): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956) 02-22 09:27:27.693: E/AndroidRuntime(554): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981) 02-22 09:27:27.693: E/AndroidRuntime(554): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123) 02-22 09:27:27.693: E/AndroidRuntime(554): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147) 02-22 09:27:27.693: E/AndroidRuntime(554): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 02-22 09:27:27.693: E/AndroidRuntime(554): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 02-22 09:27:27.693: E/AndroidRuntime(554): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424) 02-22 09:27:27.693: E/AndroidRuntime(554): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 02-22 09:27:27.693: E/AndroidRuntime(554): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 02-22 09:27:27.693: E/AndroidRuntime(554): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784) 02-22 09:27:27.693: E/AndroidRuntime(554): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551) 02-22 09:27:27.693: E/AndroidRuntime(554): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 02-22 09:27:27.693: E/AndroidRuntime(554): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class scrollview 02-22 09:27:27.693: E/AndroidRuntime(554): at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:691) 02-22 09:27:27.693: E/AndroidRuntime(554): at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466) 02-22 09:27:27.693: E/AndroidRuntime(554): at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 02-22 09:27:27.693: E/AndroidRuntime(554): at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 02-22 09:27:27.693: E/AndroidRuntime(554): at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:251) 02-22 09:27:27.693: E/AndroidRuntime(554): at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835) 02-22 09:27:27.693: E/AndroidRuntime(554): at org.example.sudoku.About.onCreate(About.java:9) 02-22 09:27:27.693: E/AndroidRuntime(554): at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465) 02-22 09:27:27.693: E/AndroidRuntime(554): at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049) 02-22 09:27:27.693: E/AndroidRuntime(554): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920) 02-22 09:27:27.693: E/AndroidRuntime(554): ... 11 more 02-22 09:27:27.693: E/AndroidRuntime(554): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.scrollview 02-22 09:27:27.693: E/AndroidRuntime(554): at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61) 02-22 09:27:27.693: E/AndroidRuntime(554): at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501) 02-22 09:27:27.693: E/AndroidRuntime(554): at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461) 02-22 09:27:27.693: E/AndroidRuntime(554): at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:552) 02-22 09:27:27.693: E/AndroidRuntime(554): at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:636) 02-22 09:27:27.693: E/AndroidRuntime(554): at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66) 02-22 09:27:27.693: E/AndroidRuntime(554): at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:653) 02-22 09:27:27.693: E/AndroidRuntime(554): at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:678) 02-22 09:27:27.693: E/AndroidRuntime(554): ... 20 more 02-22 09:30:52.675: E/AndroidRuntime(582): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 02-22 09:30:52.675: E/AndroidRuntime(582): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.example.sudoku/org.example.sudoku.About}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class scrollview 02-22 09:30:52.675: E/AndroidRuntime(582): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956) 02-22 09:30:52.675: E/AndroidRuntime(582): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981) 02-22 09:30:52.675: E/AndroidRuntime(582): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123) 02-22 09:30:52.675: E/AndroidRuntime(582): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147) 02-22 09:30:52.675: E/AndroidRuntime(582): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 02-22 09:30:52.675: E/AndroidRuntime(582): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 02-22 09:30:52.675: E/AndroidRuntime(582): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424) 02-22 09:30:52.675: E/AndroidRuntime(582): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 02-22 09:30:52.675: E/AndroidRuntime(582): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 02-22 09:30:52.675: E/AndroidRuntime(582): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784) 02-22 09:30:52.675: E/AndroidRuntime(582): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551) 02-22 09:30:52.675: E/AndroidRuntime(582): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 02-22 09:30:52.675: E/AndroidRuntime(582): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class scrollview 02-22 09:30:52.675: E/AndroidRuntime(582): at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:691) 02-22 09:30:52.675: E/AndroidRuntime(582): at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466) 02-22 09:30:52.675: E/AndroidRuntime(582): at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 02-22 09:30:52.675: E/AndroidRuntime(582): at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 02-22 09:30:52.675: E/AndroidRuntime(582): at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:251) 02-22 09:30:52.675: E/AndroidRuntime(582): at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835) 02-22 09:30:52.675: E/AndroidRuntime(582): at org.example.sudoku.About.onCreate(About.java:9) 02-22 09:30:52.675: E/AndroidRuntime(582): at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465) 02-22 09:30:52.675: E/AndroidRuntime(582): at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049) 02-22 09:30:52.675: E/AndroidRuntime(582): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920) 02-22 09:30:52.675: E/AndroidRuntime(582): ... 11 more 02-22 09:30:52.675: E/AndroidRuntime(582): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.scrollview 02-22 09:30:52.675: E/AndroidRuntime(582): at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61) 02-22 09:30:52.675: E/AndroidRuntime(582): at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501) 02-22 09:30:52.675: E/AndroidRuntime(582): at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461) 02-22 09:30:52.675: E/AndroidRuntime(582): at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:552) 02-22 09:30:52.675: E/AndroidRuntime(582): at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:636) 02-22 09:30:52.675: E/AndroidRuntime(582): at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66) 02-22 09:30:52.675: E/AndroidRuntime(582): at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:653) 02-22 09:30:52.675: E/AndroidRuntime(582): at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:678) 02-22 09:30:52.675: E/AndroidRuntime(582): ... 20 more 02-22 09:35:04.594: E/AndroidRuntime(596): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 02-22 09:35:04.594: E/AndroidRuntime(596): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.example.sudoku/org.example.sudoku.About}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class scrollview 02-22 09:35:04.594: E/AndroidRuntime(596): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956) 02-22 09:35:04.594: E/AndroidRuntime(596): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981) 02-22 09:35:04.594: E/AndroidRuntime(596): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123) 02-22 09:35:04.594: E/AndroidRuntime(596): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147) 02-22 09:35:04.594: E/AndroidRuntime(596): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 02-22 09:35:04.594: E/AndroidRuntime(596): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 02-22 09:35:04.594: E/AndroidRuntime(596): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424) 02-22 09:35:04.594: E/AndroidRuntime(596): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 02-22 09:35:04.594: E/AndroidRuntime(596): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 02-22 09:35:04.594: E/AndroidRuntime(596): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784) 02-22 09:35:04.594: E/AndroidRuntime(596): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551) 02-22 09:35:04.594: E/AndroidRuntime(596): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 02-22 09:35:04.594: E/AndroidRuntime(596): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class scrollview 02-22 09:35:04.594: E/AndroidRuntime(596): at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:691) 02-22 09:35:04.594: E/AndroidRuntime(596): at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466) 02-22 09:35:04.594: E/AndroidRuntime(596): at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 02-22 09:35:04.594: E/AndroidRuntime(596): at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 02-22 09:35:04.594: E/AndroidRuntime(596): at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:251) 02-22 09:35:04.594: E/AndroidRuntime(596): at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835) 02-22 09:35:04.594: E/AndroidRuntime(596): at org.example.sudoku.About.onCreate(About.java:9) 02-22 09:35:04.594: E/AndroidRuntime(596): at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465) 02-22 09:35:04.594: E/AndroidRuntime(596): at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049) 02-22 09:35:04.594: E/AndroidRuntime(596): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920) 02-22 09:35:04.594: E/AndroidRuntime(596): ... 11 more 02-22 09:35:04.594: E/AndroidRuntime(596): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.scrollview 02-22 09:35:04.594: E/AndroidRuntime(596): at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61) 02-22 09:35:04.594: E/AndroidRuntime(596): at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501) 02-22 09:35:04.594: E/AndroidRuntime(596): at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461) 02-22 09:35:04.594: E/AndroidRuntime(596): at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:552) 02-22 09:35:04.594: E/AndroidRuntime(596): at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:636) 02-22 09:35:04.594: E/AndroidRuntime(596): at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66) 02-22 09:35:04.594: E/AndroidRuntime(596): at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:653) 02-22 09:35:04.594: E/AndroidRuntime(596): at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:678) 02-22 09:35:04.594: E/AndroidRuntime(596): ... 20 more 02-22 09:43:32.034: E/AndroidRuntime(610): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 02-22 09:43:32.034: E/AndroidRuntime(610): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.example.sudoku/org.example.sudoku.About}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class scrollview 02-22 09:43:32.034: E/AndroidRuntime(610): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956) 02-22 09:43:32.034: E/AndroidRuntime(610): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981) 02-22 09:43:32.034: E/AndroidRuntime(610): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123) 02-22 09:43:32.034: E/AndroidRuntime(610): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147) 02-22 09:43:32.034: E/AndroidRuntime(610): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 02-22 09:43:32.034: E/AndroidRuntime(610): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 02-22 09:43:32.034: E/AndroidRuntime(610): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424) 02-22 09:43:32.034: E/AndroidRuntime(610): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 02-22 09:43:32.034: E/AndroidRuntime(610): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 02-22 09:43:32.034: E/AndroidRuntime(610): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784) 02-22 09:43:32.034: E/AndroidRuntime(610): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551) 02-22 09:43:32.034: E/AndroidRuntime(610): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 02-22 09:43:32.034: E/AndroidRuntime(610): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class scrollview 02-22 09:43:32.034: E/AndroidRuntime(610): at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:691) 02-22 09:43:32.034: E/AndroidRuntime(610): at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466) 02-22 09:43:32.034: E/AndroidRuntime(610): at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 02-22 09:43:32.034: E/AndroidRuntime(610): at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 02-22 09:43:32.034: E/AndroidRuntime(610): at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:251) 02-22 09:43:32.034: E/AndroidRuntime(610): at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835) 02-22 09:43:32.034: E/AndroidRuntime(610): at org.example.sudoku.About.onCreate(About.java:9) 02-22 09:43:32.034: E/AndroidRuntime(610): at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465) 02-22 09:43:32.034: E/AndroidRuntime(610): at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049) 02-22 09:43:32.034: E/AndroidRuntime(610): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920) 02-22 09:43:32.034: E/AndroidRuntime(610): ... 11 more 02-22 09:43:32.034: E/AndroidRuntime(610): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.scrollview 02-22 09:43:32.034: E/AndroidRuntime(610): at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61) 02-22 09:43:32.034: E/AndroidRuntime(610): at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501) 02-22 09:43:32.034: E/AndroidRuntime(610): at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461) 02-22 09:43:32.034: E/AndroidRuntime(610): at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:552) 02-22 09:43:32.034: E/AndroidRuntime(610): at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:636) 02-22 09:43:32.034: E/AndroidRuntime(610): at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66) 02-22 09:43:32.034: E/AndroidRuntime(610): at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:653) 02-22 09:43:32.034: E/AndroidRuntime(610): at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:678) 02-22 09:43:32.034: E/AndroidRuntime(610): ... 20 more

Comment: post your xml layout file for About Activity///

Comment: Is About.java contained in the Manifest.xml?

Comment: i am watching a horror movie.lol Welcome to SO please format your logcat report before posting.

Comment: I am sorry about the logcat format. just started learning

Comment: @ankit this is my about.xml file  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<scrollview
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dip">
    <textview
        android:id="@+id/about_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/about_text"/>
</scrollview>

Comment: post your about.xml File code

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <scrollview xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"; android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:padding="10dip"> <textview android:id="@+id/about_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/about_text"/> </scrollview>

Comment: @New_To_Android please click Edit on below of your question, and add any further code there only (Not in comments).. and would be nice to add that in code tag...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In about.xml Change scrollview to ScrollView and TextView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"  
    android:padding="10dip" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/about_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/about_text" />

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Thank you !!! It worked. I didnt know that it was case sensitive.. Thank you once again

Answer (score 0):

Is the buttons's onclick attribute pointing to an existing method in the activity class?

If you have

```
android:onClick="somefunction"
```

in the XML layout,

then you must have:

```
public void somefunction(View view) {
    //do stuff
}
```

in the activity

Comment: public void onClick(View v){
  switch(v.getId()) {
  case R.id.about_button:
  Intent i=new Intent(this, About.class); this is what i have in sudoku.java
  startActivity(i);
  break;
  }

Answer (score 0):

Error seeems to be here in these statements : `at org.example.sudoku.About.onCreate(About.java:9) 02-22`

Line 9 of About.java code...most prob related to setContentView()

Check your xml code that you are setting on, seems to be bug there...

Good option while debuging would be to go step by step, like say removing all your xml code here with single textview layout to see if there is problem or not... and so on....

Comment: package org.example.sudoku;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
public class About extends Activity{
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.about);    
   }
}
 this is my about.java code

Comment: there is problem with `R.layout.about` , good idea would be to start debugging from there.. look out for some reference in xml for handlers in About.java file

Comment: i did try running the application making the //setContentView(R.layout.about); line as a comment. works well!! but i dont know how to fix it